# Bootstrap: container / columns inside carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, carousel

I have added a full-width carousel to my Bootstrap template, however I would like to have a column structure inside the carousel.

So the `ol` and `li` elements should be full width, and the `.container` element should be at its max width of `1140px`.

You can see what I mean in the below screengrab (the green tint is what I'd plan to be the `.container` element:

[image: carousel]

Here is the markup I'm using:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <p>Fernatest iur? Landige nimagna tinullabo. Et eumqui quiduntem ium sumque vitiae plam nest, eturepe rovitaspidel imodis eos perum velibus rere non explabore voluptinciae volum, ut am quos con reratiis rehent liquuntur aut odit quassin ctiatur sitatus, comnis diti iusam, omnimus quunto omnis et verum laborpor accus, sunt.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </li>
</ol>
```

However this doesn't appear to work. When I look in dev tools, the `container` element appears to be shifted to the side, and the text is overflowing outside of it:

[image]

Is the `container` element not supposed to be placed inside an element such as this? Is there another way of achieving this kind of column structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to inform you , you placed your container in wrong place, you placed it in where the dots are rendered.

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="conatiner">
        Caption Slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="conatiner">
        Caption Slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="conatiner">
        Caption Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put container in .item division as the carousel-indicators are for the round icons shown in mockup in bottom of slider to navigate through slides. This might help you. Put the container division inside item division

```
'http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel'
```